# CodeIgniter retrieving joined columns and non joined one?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know this is how you call and pass columns from separate tables:

```
$this->db->select('ut.Username,ct.Title',false); 
$this->db->from('username_table AS ut');
$this->db->join('content_table AS ct', 'ct.UserID = ut.UserID');
$query = $this->db->get('content_table');
return $query->result_array();
```

But because I only select Username and Title, I can't call other remaining columns from either of the tables. How can I do that?

I tried to change the SELECT to(to get the data of the Body column from content_table):

```
 $this->db->select('ut.Username,ct.Title','ct.Body',false);
```

but it didint work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
$this->db->select('ut.Username,ct.*',false); 
    $this->db->from('username_table ut');
    $this->db->join('content_table ct', 'ct.UserID = ut.UserID');
    $query = $this->db->get('content_table');
    return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
$this->db->select('ut.Username,ct.Title','ct.Body',false);
```

try:

```
$this->db->select('ut.Username,ct.Title,ct.Body',false);
```